# How to reiterate over two for loops simultaneously in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am trying to execute a command that needs two input files, both being specific to each sample. My solution was to use two for loops:

```
FILES=testgroup/*split.bam
TARGETS=testgroup/*intervals

for f in $FILES
do
for t in $TARGETS
do

IndelRealigner -Input1 $f Input2 $t Output $f.realigned.bam

done
done
```

But when I execute this bash loops over the second for loop ($t) with the first being constant, then repeats the cycle.

I need the inputs to cycle simultaneously (ie. $f Sample1 and $t Sample1, $f Sample2 and $t Sample2).

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

Example sample names and the associated input files:

D8.1.112.fastqAligned.out.sam.rg_added_sorted.bam.dedup.bam.split.bam
D8.1.112.fastqAligned.out.sam.rg_added_sorted.bam.dedup.bam.split.bam.intervals

In the mean time I have moved the two sets of files into a new directory to see if I can then specify two groups within a single array? I am lost on how to do this though. So far:

```
files=testgroup/newdir    

for f in $files
do
   for t in $files
   do
   IndelRealigner -Input1 $f Input2 $t Output $f.realigned.bam
   done
done
```

Any further help is appreciated!

Comment: You have written a loop in a loop. Indent your code and this maybe more clear. Loop1 - iteration1, will run all iterations of Loop2. So goes for Loop1 - iteration2. You'll have to establish some sort of relationship between `FILES` and `TARGETS` so that you can do this in one loop. Think through you would solve this manually and apply that to the code. Perhaps share some sample file/target names and perhaps we can help figure out that pattern/relationship. Also... avoid naming your variables in all upper case as upper case variables are reserved for the system.

Comment: Thank-you for your advice, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: first read files and targets into arrays. Then use *one* loop to iterate over both arrays simultaneously:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=($(ls testgroup/*split.bam))
targets=($(ls testgroup/*intervals))
len=${#files[@]}
for ((i=0;i<$len;i++))
do
  IndelRealigner -Input1 "${files[$i]}" Input2 "${targets[$i]}" Output "${files[$i]}".realigned.bam
done
```

But keep in mind: this will work only if there are as many targets as files.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it working. I can't really identify what is wrong, but the error messages returned suggests to me it is trying to input all the 'Input 1' files at the same time.

Comment: You're right. The script was a little buggy. I fixed it. Please try again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the first set of files and derive the name of the corresponding file as you go:

```
for f in *bam; do
    IndelRealigner -Input1 "$f" -Input2 "${f}.intervals" -Output "$f.realigned.bam"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written a nested loop, and its behavior is exactly as it should be: the inner loop is performed for each iteration of the outer loop. But what you want is process two sets of related files in a single pass - you need to somehow do that in a single loop.

Try this: instead of trying to loop over `f` and `t`, figure out some `x that` is common to each pair of files. Loop over that `x`, and calculate the `f`'s and `t`'s from that `x` inside the loop.

YOU may know which file `f` goes with which file `t`, but the script doesn't. Do the related `f` and `t` files have the same prefix? then you need to loop over the list of prefixes. Are they numbered? Then you need a numeric loop. Is it merely a positional thing (the first `f` goes with the first `t`)? In that case it matters whether you sort the lists or not!

Without more info we can't help you in more than general terms.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated my post. The input files do have a common prefix ('D8.1.112' changes with each pair) but I am struggling to see how to implement this.